# Angularjs ui bootstrap datepicker not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using ui bootstrap directive `ui-datepicker`. I have implemented the directive into my project based on the example done on the ui bootstrap documentation website.

Here is an example of my HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
        uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
        name="start_date"
        ng-model="loan.start_date"
        is-open="popup1.opened"
        datepicker-options="dateOptions"
        ng-required="true"
        close-text="Close"
    />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        <!-- ... -->
    </span>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/vendors/sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/angular-messages.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/angular-animate.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/dirPagination.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/controllers/ClientController.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/controllers/AssetController.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/controllers/CreateClientController.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/controllers/CustomerDetailsController.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/controllers/LoanApplicationController.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('widgets/daterangepicker/moment.js') }}"></script>
```

Also here is my javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('loancirrus',   ['ngMessages','ui.bootstrap','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'ngAnimate']);

app.controller('LoanApplicationController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.loan = {start_date : new Date()};
};
$scope.today();

$scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.loan.start_date = null;
};

$scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date() ,
    startingDay: 1
};

// Disable weekend selection
function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
}

$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
};

$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
    console.log($scope.popup1.opened);
};

$scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
};

$scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
};

// $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
// $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
// $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

$scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
};

$scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
};

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
var afterTomorrow = new Date();
afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
$scope.events = [
    {
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
    },
    {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'partially'
    }
];

function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
            var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

            if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                return $scope.events[i].status;
            }
        }
    }

    return '';
} }]);
```

When clicking the button to open up the datepicker it does not come up. I am puzzled of what I could be doing wrong. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. Please add the part where you bind the bootsrap reference and the controller's code to the html. 

Try to run the example on plunkr.co

Comment: Can u give us a fiddle link with code running?

Comment: @celerno I have updated my post.